# How to change MySQL Workbench interface font size?

Tags: mysql-workbench, workbench

How to change MySQL Workbench interface font size?

Please note: interface, not editor fonts.

Workbench 6.3 on Windows 8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible. Some places use the system font size (especially standard controls) and many others have hard coded font sizes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Problem is that sometimes you need magnifying glass to see anything and if you make fonts system-wide, it makes other apps having abnormally large fonts and Workbench fonts have that 'smear ink' look (not crisp), which looks atrocious. So, A for functionality, F for interface. Pity, as this is a great tool.

Comment: I hear you, but Windows has no real concept of high resolution display and on the other OSes things are not much better (even though macOS at least has high res graphics). The problem is not only font sizes, but you have to properly scale all elements (headers, node heights, grid sizes etc.). Really not an easy task.

Comment: The answer below might not be perfect but it at least partially works and helps reduce the strain on the eyes. Better than nothing.

Comment: The OP specificaly asked for the UI, not the editor (and related parts like the result grid).

Answer (score 0):

Press Edit > Prefences.. >  Fonts&Colors[image]

Comment: This doesn't allow changing all the font sizes but it's already a good improvement for SQL commands and font sizes in table rows. However for instance the tree on the left won't change. Don't be afraid to put in big numbers to see the difference.